# Changing button icon/toggling button from another thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to run a thread in the background by pressing a button placed on an `UITableViewCell`.

Now, I have a method that gets called every time the button gets pressed and it changes the icon (from play to pause) and also does other things.

If the thread finishes successfully (although you can stop it with the button on the cell), this button should transition back from the pause icon to play icon, to show that the thread is finished correctly.

I tried passing the cell itself inside the other thread, and then edit the cell button inside `dispatch_sync`. xCode here doesn't throw any errors, but the button icon does not change.

Here is the code:

```
-(void)thread:(NSDictionary*)taskAssets{
    @autoreleasepool {

        // Unpacking data
        TaskObject *taskData = taskAssets[@"taskData"];
        UILabel *statusLabel = taskAssets[@"statusLabel"];
        CustomTaskCell *cell = taskAssets[@"cell"];

        printf("Wow, this is the thread data: %s\n", [taskData.getTaskName UTF8String]);
        sleep(10);
        printf("Wow, the thread is done\n");
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell setSelected:FALSE];
            [cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            statusLabel.text = @"Status: Finished";

        });
    }
}
```

Is there some way to achieve this?

This is where the icon changing works (yes sender is the button)

```
- (IBAction)runTask:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
        [self updateStatus:@"Stopped"];
    } else {
        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pauseIcon"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
        [self updateStatus:@"Running..."];
        [self launchThread]; // This is where the thread starts...
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this code? Show some context. And you shouldn't be directly updating a cell. Update your model and then tell the table view to reload the row at that index path.

Comment: ? I use this exact method to update the button icon inside the cell (In this case I use the button action itself to do so). The difference is that the piece of code that changes the button icon (starts with `[cell.button setImage....`) doesn't work in this other thread.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can see your call to 
`[self launchThread];`

How does the sender/cell end up in the dictionary you have at 
`-(void)thread:(NSDictionary*)taskAssets`

I am not fully aware of what `@autoreleasepool` does, but maybe you can give the following a try:

```
-(void)thread:(NSDictionary*)taskAssets{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Unpacking data
        __block TaskObject *taskData = taskAssets[@"taskData"];
        __block UILabel *statusLabel = taskAssets[@"statusLabel"];
        __block CustomTaskCell *cell = taskAssets[@"cell"];

        printf("Wow, this is the thread data: %s\n", [taskData.getTaskName UTF8String]);
        sleep(10);
        printf("Wow, the thread is done\n");
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell setSelected:FALSE];
            [cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playIcon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            statusLabel.text = @"Status: Finished";
        });
    }
}
```